# Why is the difference of datetime = zero for two rows in a dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe, datetime

This  issue that  I am facing is very simple yet weird and has troubled me to no end.

I have a dataframe as follows :

```
df['datetime'] = df['datetime'].dt.tz_convert('US/Pacific') 
#converting datetime from datetime64[ns, UTC] to datetime64[ns,US/Pacific]

df.head()

                vehicle_id  trip_id                                 datetime    
        6760612 1000500 4f874888ce404720a203e36f1cf5b716    2017-01-01 10:00:00-08:00       
        6760613 1000500 4f874888ce404720a203e36f1cf5b716    2017-01-01 10:00:01-08:00    
        6760614 1000500 4f874888ce404720a203e36f1cf5b716    2017-01-01 10:00:02-08:00      
        6760615 1000500 4f874888ce404720a203e36f1cf5b716    2017-01-01 10:00:03-08:00       
        6760616 1000500 4f874888ce404720a203e36f1cf5b716    2017-01-01 10:00:04-08:00

df.info ()

vehicle_id         int64
trip_id            object
datetime           datetime64[ns, US/Pacific]
```

I am trying to find out the datatime difference as follows ( in two different ways) :

```
df['datetime_diff'] = df['datetime'].diff()

df['time_diff'] = (df['datetime'] - df['datetime'].shift(1)).astype('timedelta64[s]')
```

For a particular trip_id, I have the results as follows :

```
df[trip_frame['trip_id'] == '4f874888ce404720a203e36f1cf5b716'][['datetime','datetime_diff','time_diff']].head()

        datetime                  datetime_diff time_diff
6760612 2017-01-01 10:00:00-08:00   NaT             NaN
6760613 2017-01-01 10:00:01-08:00   00:00:01        1.0
6760614 2017-01-01 10:00:02-08:00   00:00:01        1.0
6760615 2017-01-01 10:00:03-08:00   00:00:01        1.0
6760616 2017-01-01 10:00:04-08:00   00:00:01        1.0
```

But for some other trip_ids like the below, you can observe that I am having the datetime difference as zero (for both the columns) when it is actually not.There is a time difference in seconds.

```
df[trip_frame['trip_id'] == '01b8a24510cd4e4684d67b96369286e0'][['datetime','datetime_diff','time_diff']].head(4)

         datetime            datetime_diff  time_diff
3236107 2017-01-28 03:00:00-08:00   0 days  0.0
3236108 2017-01-28 03:00:01-08:00   0 days  0.0
3236109 2017-01-28 03:00:02-08:00   0 days  0.0
3236110 2017-01-28 03:00:03-08:00   0 days  0.0

df[df['trip_id'] == '01c2a70c25e5428bb33811ca5eb19270'][['datetime','datetime_diff','time_diff']].head(4)

        datetime             datetime_diff  time_diff
8915474 2017-01-21 10:00:00-08:00   0 days  0.0
8915475 2017-01-21 10:00:01-08:00   0 days  0.0
8915476 2017-01-21 10:00:02-08:00   0 days  0.0
8915477 2017-01-21 10:00:03-08:00   0 days  0.0
```

Any leads as to what the actual issue is ? I will be very grateful.

Comment: Can you post a portion of your data for testing the code?

Comment: The data is quite huge. Is the above data & info not helpful ?

Comment: Just a portion of data would work so that I can reproduce your error.

Answer (score 0):

If I just execute your code without the type conversion, everything looks fine:

```
df.timestamp - df.timestamp.shift(1)
```

On the example lines

```
rows=['2017-01-21 10:00:00-08:00',
 '2017-01-21 10:00:01-08:00',
 '2017-01-21 10:00:02-08:00',
 '2017-01-21 10:00:03-08:00',
 '2017-01-21 10:00:03-08:00']  # the above lines are from your example. I just invented this last line to have one equal entry
df= pd.DataFrame(rows, columns=['timestamp'])
df['timestamp']= df['timestamp'].astype('datetime64')
df.timestamp - df.timestamp.shift(1)
```

The last line returns

```
Out[40]: 
0        NaT
1   00:00:01
2   00:00:01
3   00:00:01
4   00:00:00
Name: timestamp, dtype: timedelta64[ns]
```

That looks unsuspicious so far. Note, that you already have a timedelta64 series.

If I now add your conversion, I get:

```
(df.timestamp - df.timestamp.shift(1)).astype('timedelta64[s]')
Out[42]: 
0    NaN
1    1.0
2    1.0
3    1.0
4    0.0
Name: timestamp, dtype: float64
```

You see, that the result is a series of floats. This is probably because there is a `NaN` in the series. One other thing is the additon `[s]`. This doesn't seem to work. If you use `[ns]` it seems to work. If you want to get rid of the nano seconds somehow, I guess you need to do it separately.

Comment: If I  use `df['timestamp']= df['timestamp'].astype('datetime64') `,  I obtain the following - `TypeError: cannot astype a timedelta from [timedelta64[ns]] to [datetime64]` ,that is, date-time is in timedelta64 type already.  And my main issue is that the **datetime difference** is zero when it should not be. **Format of the datetime difference** is immaterial.

Comment: How can the type of the datetime difference be immaterial, or are you only referring to the outupt format. Please don't apply the `.astype('datetime64')` to your data. I just used it to prepare my testdata in a way I think your data looks like (say: convert from string to timestamp). You don't need this step. From what I observed `df.timestamp - df.timestamp.shift(1)` should already give you, what you want. If that is not the case, I cannot help you any further without some test data and the output of `your_df.dtypes`. Thanks for your patience.

Comment: Yeah , I am referring to the output format. Have updated the question with datatypes of the features. And I should thank you for your efforts in solving my issue.

Comment: Thank's for the data, that made clear, what you mean. Are you sure that inbetween your records for `01b8a24510cd4e4684d67b96369286e0` are no other records, that may spoil your results? I mean, is the dataset sorted in index order, or did you sort it otherwise and just within the same `trip_id` the index was preserved? if it is sorted in index, I think what you observed is a bug and should be reported.

Comment: If you are not sure, you could try to figure that out by doing a `reset_index` verify that your problem still persists on the reindexed dataframe and then select the conflicting records over the newly inserted column that holds the old index. If that only selects the records from your post with delta=0 where it shouldn't be 0 ond no records which don't belong to the same trip_id, I think you should open a bug ticket.